# Comparing two groups with the linear model

Tags: r, regression, subset

I want to do a regression when parendiv is my Dependent variable and routine1997 is my Independent variable, and compare males to females[image]. The code is like this:

```
structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("male", 
"female"), class = "factor"), parent = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("intact", "parentaldivorce"), class = "factor"), 
    routine = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Med", 
    "High", "Low"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(3L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 34L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code and I want to specifically compare coefficient among men and women.

`lm(parent~routine, data=nlsy97, subset=gender)`

Comment: Fit the model with gender as a dummy variable: `out <- lm(parent ~ routine + gender, data=nlsy97); summary(out)`.  Then look at the estimated coefficient for gender.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to compare the coefficients.
The easiest way would be to code gender as dummy (0/1) and include an interaction term in the model. Then, you get the difference the gender makes for the coefficient, complete with a p-value:

`out = lm(parent ~ routine + gender + routine*gender, data=nlsy97)`

The other way would be to use a multigroup regression and comparing the pooled regression model (all genders included) with the unpooled models (seperate slopes or intercepts or both for genders). The model with the smallest AIC fits the data best. If your random slope model yields the lowest AIC, you have gender differences in your effect. If the random intercept is best, you just have level differences between the genders but may assume equal effects.

```
library(lme4)
pooled = lm(parent ~ routine, data=nlsy97)
r.inter = lmer(parent ~ routine + (1|gender), data=nlsy97)
r.slope = lmer(parent ~ routine + (routine|gender), data=nlsy97)
r.unpooled = lmer(parent ~ routine + (1+routine|gender), data=nlsy97)

AIC(pooled)
AIC(r.inter)
AIC(r.slope)
AIC(r.unpooled)
```

Using the method `coefficients()` on the model with the lowest AIC provides you with the exact coefficients for the individual groups.

EDIT: I just noticed that you just have 20 cases in total. If this is your whole dataset you should probably not do any statistical analyses at all.